# CSS Background image doesn't display in Firefox but does in IE

Tags: css, background-image, stylesheet

I have a CSS file that will display a background image in IE, but that same background image won't in firefox.  Specifically, its the headerdoc image that's the problem, the one above the menu.

What I'm trying to do is create a main div section and then create the rest of the layout in sections.

Yes, I know you could do this with a table, yuck, ugly hard to manage and even more difficult to maintain not to mention its ugly, hard to manage and even more difficult to manage.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. Here is what I'm trying to accomplish - I have a page that is the full width and heighth of the screen minus a 2.5% margin around the edges.  No biggy here, that's working just fine.

within that container I have a header section called #headerDoc.  That should be the full width of the parent container and x % in heighth.  It is here that I want to have a background covering the full area of this container.

Within the header section I have a menu section that will comprise just the bottom edge of the #headerDoc parent.  say 10% of the bottom.  This has its own background so its colored correctly.

After that I'll finish building out the rest of the screen.  But that is what I'm attempting to do here.

Here is the CSS data:

```
/************************* ID's *************************/
#mainDoc {
   margin-top: 2.5%;
   margin-right: 2.5%;
   margin-bottom: 2.5%;
   margin-left: 2.5%;
   background-color: #494948;
}

#headerDoc {
   width="100%";
   height="10%";
   background-image: url('./images/bg1.jpg');
}

#menu {
   /* position: relative;*/
   width: 100%;
   height: 32px;
   margin-top: 50px;
   /* font-size: 14px;*/
   font-size: 1em;
   font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
   /* font-weight: bold;*/
   text-align: center;
   /*     text-shadow: 3px 2px 1px #FFFFFF; */
   background-image: url('./images/dpmenu.gif');
   /* background-color: #8AD9FF;*/
   background-color: #494948;
   border-radius: 8px;
}

#menu ul {
   height: auto;
   padding: 8px 0px;
   margin: 0px;
}
#menu li {
   display: inline;
   padding: 10px;
}

#menu a {
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #ffffff;
   padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
}

#menu a:hover {
   color: #000000;
}
```

Here is the html use of the tags

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="Style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<title>Css Test</title>
</head>
   <body>
   <div id="mainDoc">
      <div id="headerDoc">
         <div id="menu">
            <ul class="bdr-t bdr-b">
               <li class="bdr-r ctr"><a href="index.php">HOME</a></li>
               <li class="bdr-r ctr"><a href="classifieds.php">CLASSIFIEDS</a></li>
               <li class="bdr-r ctr"><a href="placeadd.php">PLACE AD</a></li>
               <li class="bdr-r ctr"><a href="directory.php">DIRECTORY</a></li>
               <li class="bdr-r ctr"><a href="helpdesk.php">HELP DESK</a></li>
               <li><a href="account.php">MANAGE ACCOUNT</a></li>
           </ul>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

---

Sorry about the "=" I missed that one (had a few others I forgot the syntax for, but even after changing those it still didn't make a diff.

Comment: what is the idea to set width="100%" instead of width:100%; in your style sheet ?

Comment: remove '=' in css and use ':'

Answer (score 0):

Try

#menu ul { ... background-image: url('./images/dpmenu.gif'); .... }

by the way, whats in 
bdr-t,
bdr-b, 
bdr-r, 
ctr css class?

Comment: The bdr-t, etc. just applies lines to the menu line its not having any issue.  The menu background is working just fine, so I'm not sure what your asking me to do.

Comment: Ok,Quest. is not yet clear ... it may be simple ... Got pics? and check out http://css3please.com/‎